# Fetching image name using REGEX

Tags: javascript, regex

I have an image within image tag

```
<img alt=\"\" src=\"https://my.guidedoc.co/frontend/download.php?file=5a2b0fe5cc7f8004d975b6df7d4e3233.PNG&amp;filename=Figure 1 Summary of diagnosis of sepsis.PNG\" style=\"height:295px; width:799px\" />
```

Want to extract the fileame "Figure 1 Summary of diagnosis of sepis.PNG" which is at the end of the link using regex. Can anyone help?

Comment: have you figured out how to extract src value from img node?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try:

```js
var rx = new RegExp("filename=([^\\\\\"]+)");
var textvar = "<img alt=\\\"\\\" src=\\\"https:\/\/my.guidedoc.co\/frontend\/download.php?file=5a2b0fe5cc7f8004d975b6df7d4e3233.PNG&amp;filename=Figure 1 Summary of diagnosis of sepsis.PNG\\\" style=\\\"height:295px; width:799px\\\" \/>";
var match = rx.exec(textvar)[1];
document.write(match);
```